# Android - callbackFlow in Singleton class

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

When I have my Location Provider as a Singleton, and assume I don't have the location permission and my condition closes the flow.

Then calling `highAccuracyLocationFlow()` function won't create callbackFlow again.

If I remove the @singleton, it works but creates multiple instances of the class for each subscriber.

How can I go about it?

```
@Singleton
class DefaultLocationProvider @Inject constructor(
@ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
private val fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient,
) : LocationProvider {

init {
    Timber.d("init: ")
}

private val _receivingLocationUpdates: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> =
    MutableStateFlow(false)

override val receivingLocationUpdates: StateFlow<Boolean>
    get() = _receivingLocationUpdates

private var _lastKnownLocation : Location? = null

override fun getLastKnownLocation(): Location? {
    return _lastKnownLocation
}

private lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest

private val highAccuracyLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
    interval = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2)
    fastestInterval = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)
    priority = Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    smallestDisplacement = 0f
}

private val balancedPowerLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
    interval = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(60)
    fastestInterval = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30)
    priority = Priority.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
    smallestDisplacement = 50f
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private val _locationUpdates = callbackFlow {
    val callback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(result: LocationResult) {
            Timber.d("New location: ${result.lastLocation.toString()}")
            // Send the new location to the Flow observers
            _lastKnownLocation = result.lastLocation
            result.lastLocation?.let {
                trySend(it).isSuccess
            }
        }
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) close()

    Timber.d("Starting location updates")
    _receivingLocationUpdates.value = true

    fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
        locationRequest,
        callback,
        Looper.getMainLooper()
    ).addOnFailureListener { e ->
        e.printStackTrace()
        close(e) // in case of exception, close the Flow
    }

    awaitClose {
        Timber.d("Stopping location updates")
        _receivingLocationUpdates.value = false
        fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(callback) // clean up when Flow collection ends
    }
}.shareIn(
    MainScope(),
    replay = 1,
    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed()
)

override fun highAccuracyLocationFlow(): Flow<Location> {
    Timber.d("highAccuracyLocationFlow req")
    locationRequest = highAccuracyLocationRequest
    return _locationUpdates
}

override fun balancedPowerLocationFlow(): Flow<Location> {
    locationRequest = balancedPowerLocationRequest
    return _locationUpdates
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Side note, I see a bug in your code. You used `_locationUpdates` with `shareIn` so there can only be one session of `requestLocationUpdates` going on at a time. So if you call `balancedPowerLocationFlow()` and start collecting that flow, followed by calling `highAccuracyLocationFlow()` while there is still a subscriber of the balanced power flow, it will remain as a balanced power flow even for the new subscriber.

---

Here are a couple of different strategies for the issue you're asking about:

1. Mark your two functions with `@RequiresPermission(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)` so you are leaving it up to the caller to only get the Flow reference if it knows the permission is already granted. The annotation helps catch some situations where you accidentally forget to check for the permission first. If you do this, you can remove the safety check that closes the Flow.
2. Create an internal Channel for tracking when the permission has been granted. Any class that uses this class can be responsible for informing it when permission has been granted (or that permission has already been granted).

```
private val permissionGrantedChannel = Channel<Unit>()

fun notifyLocationPermissionGranted() {
    permissionGrantedChannel.trySend(Unit)
}
```

Then you can replace your `if(/*...*/) close()` with `permissionGrantedChannel.receive()` so the Flow simply suspends until it is known that the permissions have been granted.

Edit: Actually, this should probably be a MutableStateFlow instead of channel so when your flow gets restarted due to falling to 0 subscribers momentarily, the true value is already there. I put this version in the code below.

---

Here is a potential strategy for the issue I mentioned at the top. I didn't test this. The idea here is that we keep track in a StateFlow of how many high-accuracy subscriptions are currently being collected and use `flatMapLatest` on that to automatically restart our flow with the right type of location updates whenever we move between 0 and 1 collectors that require high accuracy.

A high-accuracy flow is wrapped at the start and end with making updates to that StateFlow, but otherwise is just passing through the same flow as you would get if requesting balanced updates. So there is only ever one location request going on at once. Collectors that only want balanced updates will simply get temporarily swapped to high accuracy whenever there is at least one high accuracy collector simultaneously getting updates.

Note, this is just to illustrate the concept. I removed a lot of your boilerplate just for brevity.

```
private val scope = MainScope() + CoroutineName("DefaultLocationProvider CoroutineScope")
private var highAccuracyCollectorCount = 0
private val isHighAccuracy = MutableStateFlow(false)
private val permissionGranted = MutableStateFlow(false)

fun notifyLocationPermissionGranted() {
    permissionGranted.value = true
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
val balancedPowerLocations = isHighAccuracy.flatMapLatest { shouldUseHighAccuracy ->
    callbackFlow {
        val callback = object : LocationCallback() {
            //...
        }
        permissionGranted.first { it }

        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            locationRequest,
            callback,
            Looper.getMainLooper()
        ).addOnFailureListener { e ->
            e.printStackTrace()
            close(e) // in case of exception, close the Flow
        }
        awaitClose {
            fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(callback)
        }
    }
}
    .distinctUntilChanged() // in case switching callbacks tries to replay the last known location
    .shareIn(scope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), replay = 1)

val highAccuracyLocations = balancedPowerLocations
    .onStart {
        isHighAccuracy.value = true
        highAccuracyCollectorCount++
    }
    .onCompletion {
        isHighAccuracy.value = --highAccuracyCollectorCount > 0
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Man! 
I must say, you summarised it really well.

How do you suggest I should switch to "balancedPowerLocationFlow" for let's say when I put the app to background and my service unbinds.

Comment: I have one idea for that. See my updated answer. But if your app is in the background, you're not going to get any updates at all unless you register for updates in a foreground Service.

Comment: The problem with this is that now I can only have one subscriber for each type of location requests. 
Let's say, I want to have a subscriber at my foreground service regardless of what I have in my fragments. Cuz I'm sending the location updates to the server from the service only, and using fragment observers to show location on map fragment.

Comment: I don't follow what you're saying. I don't know what you're doing with services and fragments, etc.

Comment: I have a foreground service where I subscribe to the location flow (high or balanced, based on certain conditions) and upload the locations to the server regardless of if my app is open or not.

So, If I subscribe to a flow inside the app like in a fragment, and then close the app that flow closes and the service flow is also closed with it.

Could there be a better approach to this?

Comment: I don’t understand why closing the activity would stop the flow from producing values for the service. You’ll want to turn it into a SharedFlow at a layer of your app that is upstream of both your Fragment(ViewModel) and Service,

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate on that?

Let's say I want to use "balanced power location flow" when the user exits the app, and I want to use "high power location flow" when the user exits the app but he has himself set as online.

My fragments will always use "high power location flow" and I stop that flow when my fragment is stopped.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: My main concern here is switching from highAccuracy to balancedPowerAccuracy...

Comment: That's what my suggested solution is supposed to do automatically, although I didn't test it. There is only one shared flow under the hood here. It automatically switches itself to high accuracy if the high-accuracy-specific flow has any collectors, and automatically switches back if that high-accuracy-specific flow has no collectors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248770/discussion-between-mohsin-falak-and-tenfour04).

Comment: Ok, it's working. But I think there's a bug in (Pixel 3 Android 12). When I kill the app, I'm receiving the high accuracy location logs but the GPS icon is gone from the status bar.

Funny thing is, it only happens on my Pixel device, not on Samsung or Xiaomi with same Android version.

Comment: I'm just suggesting a potential strategy to solve the problem. I don't have time to test and debug it...